# jQuery submit 'this' form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to submit a form, once the user has accepted they want to continue via the jQuery UI Dialog.

```
<form method="POST" action="url" onsubmit="return APP.dom.confirm(this);">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
</form>
```

My `APP.dom.confirm` method looks like:

```
 confirm: function(form) {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
       modal: true,
       buttons: {
          "Confirm": function() {
             $(form).submit();
          },
          "Cancel": function() {
             $(this).dialog("close" );
          }
       }
    });

    return false;
 }
```

This works, however when they click confirm I'd like the form to get submitted.

```
$(form).submit();
```

That doesn't work. Logging it out I get the above HTML back. I've tried variations of, to no avail:

```
$(form).clostest('form').submit();
```

How do I submit `this`?

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
$(form).submit();
```

to

```
form.submit();
```

When you call `submit` on a jQuery object, it calls your submit handler again. Calling it directly on the DOM element does not.

Example *(interestingly, Stack Snippets won't let me submit a form, not even with target="_blank")*:

```js
var nesting = 0;
function submitHandler(form) {
  var which = $(form).find("input[type=radio]:checked").val();
  ++nesting;
  if (nesting > 5) {
    snippet.log("Nested to 5, gave up");
  } else {
    if (which === "jQuery") {
      snippet.log("Calling via jQuery, nesting = " + nesting);
      $(form).submit();
    } else {
      snippet.log("Calling via DOM, nesting = " + nesting);
      form.submit();
    }
  }
  --nesting;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="the-form"
      onsubmit="return submitHandler(this);"
      action="http://www.google.com/search"
      target="_blank"
      method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="q" value="kittens">
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="opts" value="jQuery"> Submit with jQuery
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="opts" value="DOM"> Submit with DOM
    </label>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ahhh I see, guess I got too sucked into jQuery. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
confirm: function() {
var that = this;
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
       modal: true,
       buttons: {
          "Confirm": function() {
             $(that).submit();
          },
          "Cancel": function() {
             $(this).dialog("close" );
          }
       }
    });
}
```

Replace `onsubmit="return APP.dom.confirm(this);"` by
    $('form').on('submit', APP.dom.confirm);